# If $\partial E$ has Jordan outer measure zero, then $E$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I am going through Tao's measure theory book, and have to prove

> If $\partial E$ has Jordan outer measure zero, then $E$ is measurable.

where $\partial E$ denotes the boundary of the set $E$.

I was able to prove this by first showing that any path from the interior to the exterior of $E$ must pass through $\partial E$, and using this to state that if $O$ is an elementary set which covers $\partial E$, then $E\backslash O$ is an elementary set. I then defined $A=E\backslash O$ and $B=O\cup A$, in which case $A\subset E\subset B$ and $m(B\backslash A)=m(O)$ where the right hand side can be arbitrarily small.

This proof however seems overly complicated. This is actually part 3 in a question, where the first two parts were to prove that the exterior measure of $E$ is equal to the exterior measure of the closure, and the interior measure of $E$ is equal to the interior measure of its interior. Is there any way to write a simpler proof, possibly using these facts? I tried to do it, but had trouble passing between the exterior and interior measures.